# Select is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have tried all the possibilities but the error still appears:

> select.java:4: error: Select is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Select extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton admin;
    JButton user;
JPanel panel;
public Select()
{
    admin=new JButton("admin");
    user=new JButton("user");
    panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    panel.add(admin);
    panel.add(user);
    //admin.addActionListener();
    admin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            Login page=new Login();
            page.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    user.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent b) {
            Login page=new Login();
            page.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
   class selection
    {
        public static void main(String arg[])
         {
            try
            {
                Select frame=new Select();
                frame.setSize(300,200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using anonymous classes as action listeners for `user` and `admin`. You aren't using `Select` as an action listener, so simply remove the `implements ActionListener` from the declaration of `class Select`.

Alternatively, add the required method to `Select`:

```
class Select extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ...

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, from the code you posted, there is no need for `Select` to implement `ActionListener`.